# Dropwizard resource test, Jackson not populating field, deserializing and serializing?

Tags: hibernate, unit-testing, jersey, jackson, dropwizard

I have a basic resource test that uses a `ResourceTestRule` to run my resource and Jersey as the client to make the request - most of this was taken directly from the docs. The problem is I want to 1) validate a `User` object on `create`, and 2) NOT serialize the salt and password when going from Object -> JSON, as a catchall so these are never exposed in responses.

The test fails and returns a 422 with no content. The Hibernate validation error message never makes it through so the only thing I end up seeing is the failure of the `Response.Status.OK` assertion. I have a validation constraint on `password` which is `@NotEmpty` - commenting this out makes the test pass. I am also `@JsonIgnore`ing the password getter since it was convenient and made it so it would never be exposed in a JSON response, but I'm open to doing this a different way. My best guess is that somewhere in the internals of Hibernate/Jersey the Entity I pass to the Jersey request (the `Entity.entity(user, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)`) is getting deserialized and serialized again, and the password is getting lost because it can't be gotten.

Here is the test rule:

```
@ClassRule public static final ResourceTestRule
    userResource =
    ResourceTestRule.builder().addResource(new UserResource(USER_DAO, PERSON_DAO)).build();
```

The test body which fails at `assertThat(response.getStatusInfo()).isEqualTo(Response.Status.OK);`:

```
when(USER_DAO.save(any(User.class))).thenReturn(Optional.of(user));
when(PERSON_DAO.save(any(Person.class))).thenReturn(Optional.of(person));

final Response
response =
userResource.client().target("/user").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
  .post(Entity.entity(user, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));

assertThat(response.getStatusInfo()).isEqualTo(Response.Status.OK);
verify(USER_DAO).save(userCaptor.capture());
verify(PERSON_DAO).save(personCaptor.capture());
User savedUser = userCaptor.getValue();
assertThat(savedUser).isEqualToIgnoringGivenFields(user, "salt", "password", "person");
assertThat(savedUser.getPerson()).isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively(user.getPerson());
```

Here is the actual resource method:

```
@POST
@Timed
  public User create(@NotNull @Valid User user) {
    if (user.getPerson() != null) {
      try {
        personDAO.save(user.getPerson());
        // todo justin - abstract this
      } catch (DuplicateKeyException e) {
        throw new WebApplicationException("That person exists already.", Response.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
      }
    }

    try {
      user = userDAO.save(user).get();
    } catch (DuplicateKeyException e) {
      throw new WebApplicationException("That user exists already.", Response.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    return user;
  }
```

Here is the expected user (the one I'm returning from the mock `UserDAO`):

```
user = new User();
user.setEmail("justin@email.com");
user.setPassword("test");

person = new Person();
person.setFirstName("Justin");
person.setLastName("K");

user.setPerson(person);
```

And the relevant portion of the `User` class:

```
public class User extends BaseModel implements Principal {
  @Id
  @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
  private ObjectId id = new ObjectId();

  @Email
  @NotBlank
  private String email;

  @NotEmpty
  private byte[] password;

  private byte[] salt = Security.getSalt();

  public ObjectId getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(ObjectId id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }

  @JsonIgnore // ignored when serialized FROM object TO json
  public byte[] getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  @JsonProperty
  public void setPassword(byte[] password) {
    this.password = password;
  }

  @JsonProperty
  public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = Security.hashPassword(password.toCharArray(), this.getSalt());
  }

  @JsonIgnore // ignored when serialized FROM object TO json
  public byte[] getSalt() {
    return salt;
  }

  @JsonProperty
  public void setSalt(byte[] salt) {
    this.salt = salt;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see a way around this. Instead of:

```
Entity.entity(user, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
```

you could try using the actual user's json (crafted by hand). But of course, if you use the same code for production (and not just for tests) then it won't work.

Comment: Yeah, I considered that. I would probably do that if there were no other way, but it'd be a shame to not be able to use the built in tools for testing.